# deploying asp.net mvc4 app with EF 5.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am pretty new to asp.net mvc development. I have developed an asp.net mvc4 app targeting .NET 4.0 and using EF 5.0 for database connection. Now I want to deploy this app in a Windows 2008 server with IIS 7.5. What are the things I need to make sure that are installed in the server for this application to work properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only two: .NET 4.0 and optionally MVC 4. You can avoid installing MVC 4 if you include binaries in your deployment package.

EF5 you standard .NET 4.0 and for sure you have reference to it, so all needed binaries will be in deployment package

Answer (score 0):

Download MS Web Platform Installer 4.6 if you haven't already on the new Windows 2008 server.

http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Search for 'Recommended' in the top right search box.

Select and install 'Recommended Server Configuration for Hosting Providers'.

This will install all SQL drivers etc (probably too much in fairness, but in fewer steps) that you need to run .net 4.5 apps, and make it possible to deploy using Web Deploy.

The details of the process can be found in this article

http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/gabe/how-to-install-webdeploy-on-windows-server-2012/